# XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange is not called when the javascrpt method is called from HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function which should call a servlet and evaluate the response. The servlet is called correctly and does its work, but onreadystatechange is not called for state 4. My coding is:

```
function changeUser () {
    var newEmailWidget = document.getElementById("newEmail");
    newEmail = newEmailWidget.value;
    var newPasswordWidget = document.getElementById("newPassword");
    newPassword = newPasswordWidget.value;

    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhr = new ActiceXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }

    url = "myurl";
    var params = "newEmail=" + newEmail + "&newPassword=" + newPassword;
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(params);
}
```

In the case where I need the function, it is called from a HTML form:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" onsubmit="changeOfficeUser()">
...
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

For test purpose I inserted a call of the same functin in another JSP page which has a table and a button in each table line. From that page it works: The javascript method is called, it calles the servlet, and when the servlet is finished, onreadystatechange in my javascript function is called. The calling snippet of that JSP page is:

```
<table width="700px" align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action = "GenerateRegioPoints">
                <tr>
                    <td>some data</td>
                    <td><input type="button" onclick="changeUser()" value="Change" /></td>
                </tr>
            </form> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why is onreadystatechange not called in the first case where the javascript method is called via onsubmit from the form? Or how do I call the javascript function correctly?

Thank you for your help.
Best regards
Gerhard

Comment: The function is `changeUser()`, not `changeOfficeUser()`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a typo in the function name which you have defined and which you are using in the form.
Also you should prevent the default behaviour of the form submit:

Pass the event from submit action

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" onsubmit="changeOfficeUser(e)">
```

and preventing it's default behaviour in JS by using

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not preventing the normal form submission, so the page is reloading and the JS from the original page stops.

Use `return false` in the `onsubmit` to prevent the default action.

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" onsubmit="changeOfficeUser(); return false;">
```